# why is my jstl <c:if test="(should be true)"> returning even the false items?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a list of object values, one of the fields of each object value is boolean named "displayable".

here's my code:

```
<% int z = 1 %>
<c:forEach var="value" items="${valueList}" varStatus="status">
    <% String className = (z % 2 == 1) ? "Odd" : ""; %>
    <li class="<%= className %>">
        <c:if test="${value.displayable}"> 
            /* there are ten items in that list
            8 of the value.displayable are true
            2 are false */

            <a href=""> title </a>
            <a href=""> link </a>
        </c:if>
    </li>
    <% ++z; %>
</c:forEach>
```

From that loop i should only get items correct? somehow i am getting all 10 items.

Comment: You'll get ten `<li>` elements, but only eight of them should have `<a>` elements as children. Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: it will loop ten times and display a list item each time

Comment: @AnthonyGrist NimChimpsky ok i see it now, wow im retarded, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take your word for it regarding the fact that two of those items have `displayable == false`. In this case, I *assume* you are getting a list of 10 `<li></li>`items but two of them do not have the "title" and "link" links inside.

That's because you're rendering the `<li></li>` tags (and switching the css class, and incrementing the `z` counter) *disregarding* whether the current item is displayable or not. Put all the content of that `for` loop (scriptlets and `<li></li>`) inside the `<c:if>` so that you will only display list items when the item *is* displayable.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the code like this

```
    <c:forEach var="value" items="${valueList}" varStatus="status">
        <c:if test="${value.displayable}"> 
          <c:if test="${status.index%2==0 }">   
             <li>
                <a href=""> title </a>
                <a href=""> link </a>
            </li>
          </c:if>
          <c:if test="${status.index%2!=0 }">   
             <li class="Odd">
                <a href=""> title </a>
                <a href=""> link </a>
            </li>
         </c:if>
     </c:if>     
 </c:forEach>
```